# In Android Emulator Settings - Google Play Services version will not resolve

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, google-play-services, visual-studio-2019

Environment - Visual Studio 2019, Xamarin Android SDK v11.1.0.17.  Three Android platforms installed and each have Google Play installed:
[image]

Likewise, Google Play services enabled in the Tools tab:
[image]

In Android Device Manager, when I look at the settings for each device emulator, the Google Play Store is checked:
[image]

In the emulator Settings, the Google Play Services version just stays at Loading.
[image]

Any ideas why that version never resolves?  The downstream affect is that I can't display Google Maps in my emulator projects.

EDIT: I am running an out of the box Microsoft sample app found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/mapsandlocationdemo-v3/

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your map not showing.Have you configured the google map correctly?You could show some codes.

Comment: You may uninstall that "Play Services" version 49, as it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

After importing SDK 's below

[SDK's in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhbjr.jpg)

Then Android Studio version below

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

Open AVD Manager
[image: AVD Manager]

Pixel 2 and others below, play services coming with this emulator.

[image: AVD-2]

Then Play Store is active and automatically installed anymore...

[image: Emulator looks like]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have installed Google Play services for your emulator. You should install the 3rd last with the name ***Google API Intel x86 Atom _64 System Image*** in your Android 9.0 pie.

Sometime it even do not show the map in emulator. So you should wipe your emulator and make sure the settings you are using for emulator are present in your sdk and your project. i.e android version, google api services etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I installed Google API Intel x86 Atom _64 System Image in my Android 9.0 pie, then wiped all of my existing emulators.  I built a new emulator based on the Android 9.0 pie, yet the behavior persists.  The Google Play Services version number never resolves and maps won't load in the emulator.

Comment: Can show some code? There could be issue in your code instead of emulator. To verify this try running application in physical device.

Comment: @Inhshal I should have mentioned in my original post that I am running an out of the box Microsoft example found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/mapsandlocationdemo-v3/